# XSL 1.0: Loop through separated values

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<RESULTS>
<SEARCHRESULT RECORDS="54">
    <ROW ROWNUM="1" PKField="COUNTER">
        <COLUMN COLNUM="1" NAME="COUNTER" DATATYPE="number">1243</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN COLNUM="2" NAME="KEY" DATATYPE="number">176</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN COLNUM="3" NAME="NAME" DATATYPE="string">John Smith;Jane Doe;Alan Rickman</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN COLNUM="4" NAME="TITLE" DATATYPE="string">Secretary;Partner;Director</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN COLNUM="5" NAME="FROM_DATE" DATATYPE="date">21/04/2001;07/09/2002;27/05/2003</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN COLNUM="6" NAME="TO_DATE" DATATYPE="date">12/01/2006;14/01/2003;06/03/2006</COLUMN>
        <COLUMN COLNUM="7" NAME="DIVISION" DATATYPE="string">Retail</COLUMN>
    </ROW>
</SEARCHRESULT>
```

I'm creating a XSLT file to transform it, currently it comes out like this:

```
KEY||NAME||TITLE||FROM_DATE||TO_DATE||DIVISION176||John Smith;
Jane Doe;
Alan Rickman||Secretary;
Partner;
Director||21/04/2001;
07/09/2002;
27/05/2003||12/01/2006;
14/01/2003;
06/03/2006||Retail
```

But I'm trying to make it come out like so:

```
KEY||NAME||TITLE||FROM_DATE||TO_DATE||DIVISION
176||John Smith||Secretary||21/04/2001||12/01/2006||Retail
176||Jane Doe||Partner||07/09/2002||14/01/2003||Retail
176||Alan Rickman||Director||27/05/2003||06/03/2006||Retail
```

I'm currently trying to use the following method:

```
  <xsl:template name="loopOnSeperator">
<xsl:param name="String"/>
<xsl:param name="Counter" select="0" />
<xsl:variable name="sa" select="substring-after($String, $seperator)" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$sa != '' or contains($String, $seperator)">
      <xsl:call-template name="loopOnSeperator">
        <xsl:with-param name="String"    select="$sa" />
        <xsl:with-param name="Counter"   select="$Counter + 1" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$String" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

But I am having difficulty especially with the KEY & DIVISION fields.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your method (it's out of any context). Let me suggest a different approach:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>KEY||NAME||TITLE||FROM_DATE||TO_DATE||DIVISION&#10;</xsl:text>

    <xsl:for-each select="RESULTS/SEARCHRESULT/ROW">
        <xsl:variable name="row" select="." />

        <xsl:variable name="names">
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$row/COLUMN[@NAME='NAME']"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="titles">
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$row/COLUMN[@NAME='TITLE']"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="from-dates">
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$row/COLUMN[@NAME='FROM_DATE']"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="to-dates">
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$row/COLUMN[@NAME='TO_DATE']"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($names)/token">
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$row/COLUMN[@NAME='KEY']"/>
            <xsl:text>||</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>||</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($titles)/token[$i]"/>
            <xsl:text>||</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($from-dates)/token[$i]"/>
            <xsl:text>||</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($to-dates)/token[$i]"/>
            <xsl:text>||</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$row/COLUMN[@NAME='DIVISION']"/>
            <xsl:if test="$i!=last()">
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="';'"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string, $delimiter)">
            <token>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $delimiter)"/>
            </token>
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <token>
                <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
            </token>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please note that node-set is a non-standard function but supported in the major XSLT processors AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks very much, I've never used anything from EXSLT before but I believe I understand it. One more question, how would I implement this if I had multiple ROWs within the SEARCHRESULTs?

Comment: @goblinne It depends on how different the rows can be. I have made a small edit to my answer; see if this provides a solution. If not, please edit your question and show us the problem.

Comment: Using: <xsl:for-each select="RESULTS/SEARCHRESULT/ROW">
        <xsl:variable name="row" select="." />
solved it cheers, I was putting it in the wrong place, thank you for your time!

Comment: You're welcome. Let me just point out that the real problem here is the input. If you have any influence over that, you should try and change it because it's extremely unwise for XML to carry embedded delimited values. This task would be much easier if the person upstream of you did a proper job of structuring the data into XML elements and/or attributes.